# How to add multiple commands in discord.py

Tags: discord.py

How to add multiple commands in discord.py? If we put another commands right below it,the command will not work

Comment: can you provide us by including the code you tried? And tell us whats the problem?

Comment: Please give more details, the code, what errors have you got... Also please read [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

To create a new command you just create a new command reference:

The code:

```
@client.command()
async def command_1(ctx):
    await ctx.send("This is command #1")


@client.command()
async def command_2(ctx):
    await ctx.send("THis is command #2")
```

So for each command you just create a new `client.command()` and async def function